# Android application not visible on playstore in Asus Nexus 7 Tablet

Tags: android, google-play

I have added the below code in my Manifest file:

```
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true" />
```

But my android app is not visible on Asus Nexus 7 Tablet, what may be the issue here, should I need to add anything else here ?
Is this may be some permissions related issue ?

Please guide me, I need help here.

Thanks a lot in advanced !!!

Comment: is your android os version on asus nexus 7 matches to your compile sdk and target sdk in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have target sdk version defined to 22 and my Asus nexus 7 is having android 5.1.1 i.e. API level 22.
So, this is not an issue of target sdk version.

Do I need to add something else in the <supports-screens block to support this tab?

Comment: Why do you need this supports-screens section? Are there any screens you do not want to support? If not, remove this section completely.

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone I am facing the same issue too. Have you found the solution? I have asked a question for the same .I have cross checked for uses-permissions and uses features attributes too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592072/application-listing-for-10-inch-tablets-in-playstore-but-not-displayed-for-7-inc/36592281?noredirect=1#comment60782923_36592281